Can we define differentiable structures on topological spaces which are not manifolds?
I've been thinking about exactly how one determines differentiability of continuous maps between topological spaces. If $f$ is a map between topological vector spaces, the general idea is that $f$ should be called differentiable if it is locally linear; this is formalised in the first chapter of Lang's text. From here, we can define a differentiable structure on a manifold $M$ locally modelled on a TVS $X$ as an atlas $\{\varphi_i: U_i \to X\}_{i \in I}$ for which each transition function $\varphi_i \circ \varphi_j^{-1}$ is differentiable, and we can then call a map $f: M \to N$ differentiable if it is differentiable in coordinate charts. Thus, the notion of a differentiable map extends to every differentiable manifold (even infinite-dimensional ones).
However, I recently realised that this description misses several examples of spaces on which differentiability should make sense:

The example which motivated this question is the cone as a subspace $C \subseteq \mathbb R^3$, given by the zero set of the map $(x, y, z) \mapsto x^2 + y^2 - z^2$. $C$ is not a manifold (it is not locally Euclidean at the origin), but we should still have a way to say that any differentiable map on $\mathbb R^3$ restricts to a differentiable map on $C$.
One possible resolution is that $C$ is a subspace of a manifold, so differentiability on $C$ can be described in terms of $\mathbb R^3$. However, we can make larger spaces out of $C$, such as compactifications, which do not naturally embed in $\mathbb R^3$ as extensions of $C$ but nevertheless should have sensible differentiability. (And, in any case, it seems desirable to have notions independent of embeddings - after all, this is part of why abstract manifolds are easier to deal with.)
Finally, the set of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ endowed with the order topology is not a manifold, but notions of differentiable functions nevertheless make sense using the classical limit definition. Note that we can't describe differentiability on $\mathbb Q$ by simply restricting differentiable functions on $\mathbb R$: for instance, the indicator function of $(\sqrt{2}, \infty)$ is not differentiable on $\mathbb R$, but it is when restricted to $\mathbb Q$.

As such, I am wondering whether there are more general notions of differentiable structures which apply to arbitrary topological spaces (or really any broader class of spaces). I haven't been able to find any discussion of this problem anywhere else; are there perhaps resources which deal with these questions?
(By the way, I have no idea what tags to use for this question! If my tags are inappropriate or you know better ones, please let me know.)

There are lots of ways you might generalize differentiable structure. You can start with a manifold and relax the requirement that the basic patch is a ball. This leads you to manifolds-with-boundary, manifold-with-corners, and orbifolds.
You can relax the requirement charts be locally homeomorphic, which gives you diffeologies. Instead, you take plots, maps from open balls into your diffeology, accepting that some of them will not be injective. This seems to fit the bill of applying to general topological spaces:

"the relationship between smooth manifolds and diffeological spaces is
analogous to the relationship between topological manifolds and
topological spaces." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeology)

I don't think it will do what you want with $\mathbb Q$, though, because $\mathbb Q$ is not locally compact but $\mathbb R$ is, so every plot would be trivial.
If you look at it categorically, generalizing what differentiable structure does instead of how it's built, you get tangent bundle categories. The core insight is that the tangent bundle is a functor. It sends smooth manifolds to their tangent bundles and smooth functions to their derivatives. Once the essential properties of this functor are axiomatized, you can find other categories that have tangent bundle functors. To capture the idea of local linearity, you require a commutative $+$ operator on the tangent bundles.
We can also get more specific. A cone is an algebraic object:
$$
x^2+y^2-z^2 = 0.
$$
By leaning on algebraic structure, you can get a purely-algebraic notion of the derivative: throw away higher order terms. If you only consider polynomials and rational functions, you don't need any limiting arguments or approximations to do this. Just take
$$
f(x+h) = a + bh + ch^2 + \dots + dh^m
$$
and set $h^2=0$. This brings you to the Zariski tangent space and schemes. This does let you take derivatives in $\mathbb Q$, but it still rules out your step functions.

This is exactly what I was looking for! Just a quick idea on diffeologies on $\mathbb Q$: it seems that the incompatibility comes from the fact that we're enforcing $\mathbb R$-differentiability on our topological spaces, since the domain of a plot is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Thus, could we feasibly define a $\mathbb Q$-diffeology by taking open subsets of $\mathbb Q^n$ instead? (Or more generally, any topological vector space with a notion of differentiability?)

@BayleeV That makes sense to me!
